# Return two joined tables and one data table into an string comma separated with GROUP CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

From this tables:

```
 table_a
 id | date       | owner | space
 1  |  85408503  |  4    |  5
 2  |  52345234  |  5    |  5
 3  |  52345243  |  2    |  5

 table_b
 id | name     | age
 2  |  luis    |  32
 4  |  german  |  53
 5  |  marta   |  43

 table_c
 id | c_id       | stack |  vs 
 1  |     3      |  1    |   2
 2  |     3      |  4    |   2
 3  |     1      |  1    |   2
 4  |     3      |  4    |   3
```

I want to select every field with a specific number in table_a.space (for example table_a.space = 5) GROUP BY t1.id joined with table_b.name, where owner = table_b.id and a new column that contain concatenated separated by comma the coincidence: table_a.id = table_c.c_id also table_c.version = 2

So.. My try ( i try a lot of things using group by, using , etc with no success

so just what works without error

```
 SELECT t1.id,t1.owner,t3.vs      
 FROM table_a t1 LEFT JOIN table_b t2 ON t1.owner = t2.id 
 LEFT JOIN table_c t3 ON t1.id = t3.c_id 
 WHERE t1.space = 5 GROUP BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id
```

I know this would put into a string (if I put this after "t1.owner," it would return just one row

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.stack SEPARATOR ',') as selected
```

and I don't know where to put the coincidence for t3.vs

```
 AND t3.vs = 2
```

I would like this to return when t1.space = 5

```
id  |  owner| space | vs | selected  
 2  |  5    |  5    |  2 |
 3  |  2    |  5    |  2 | 1,4
```

and this when t1.space = 3

and this should return

```
id  |  owner| space | vs  |selected  
 3  |  2    |  5    | 2
```

Comment: your question is confusing because you switched from table_a,table_b, table_c to t1, t2 t3, and you don't seem sure about how you want them grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed your naming convention in the middle of your question. What you want is to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.owner, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.stack SEPARATOR ',') as selected
FROM table_a t1 LEFT JOIN table_b t2 ON t1.owner = t2.id 
LEFT JOIN table_c t3 ON t1.id = t3.c_id 
WHERE t1.space = 5 AND t3.vs=2
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Without the GROUP BY, you get everything grouped into 1 row. The group by tells mysql to group it by a particular column.

Comment: Thanks for the Help . I just made few modifications, and this is what I need (no need of t3.vs = 2 in WHERE clause . I try this before but using a wrong grouping then I check the manual and realized what I was doing wrong